# Filter wordpress query by numerical order arguments

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some programs that go according to the day but I want it to be filtered by custom field such as menu_order, that is, by numerical position through ordernum that I can give it

This doesn't show me the result. ordernum is a select field with integers

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'schedule', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'meta_key' => 'day',
        'meta_value' => 'Sunday',
        'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                  'key' => 'ordernum',
                  'value' => 'meta_value_num',
                  'compare' => '=',
           ),
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your meta query at the moment is filtering the results by the custom field "ordernum" with the value "meta_value_num". It seems like your value is wrong. If you want to filter the results for only posts which have ordernum = 1, then change the value to "1".

If you want to order your query by the ordernum field, you will need to add the following args

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'ordernum',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);
```